# Breaking on the line of code that is causing a Null pointer exception

Tags: eclipse

I am very new to Java and EClipse and I am running a JUnit test. When I run the test it fails and throws a Java.lang.NullPointer Exception... But it doesn't show me where in code is this happening.   In Visual Studio when such an exception happens it jumps to the exact line of code that is causing the exception. Is there anything or any setting I should set in Eclipse to be able to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're running it in the debugger rather than just as "Run". Also, in the debugger you can add ["exception breakpoints"](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/breakpoints/ref-addexception_viewaction.htm). Alternatively, just look at the stack trace of the exception - that should show you where things are going wrong...

Comment: Thanks Jon, didn't know about exception breakpoint. Will set it.